# python: Проблемы с кодировкой писем из gmail при использовании IMAP

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, imap

Добрый вечер!

Есть задача написать небольшой парсер почты gmail на python 3, основная задача которого искать нужную информацию в тексте сообщения. Сообщения приходят вида:

```
'Тревожное устройство: 3FAA06
 info[[5,6,7]]'
```

Использую протокол `IMAP`.

С помощью метода `fetch` сохраняю содержимое в переменную `msgg`.

```
msgg=M.fetch(num,'(BODY.PEEK[TEXT])')[1][0][1].strip()
```

Как известно, в получившейся огромной строке с информацией о письме, есть участок с текстом собственно сообщения. Мне важен только участок письма `info[[5,6,7]]`, который корректно отобразился бы в данной строке, если бы не было русских символов.

НО, из-за использования русских символов в совокупности с английскими символами, на участке с телом сообщения располагается закодированный текст, его фрагмент `"0KLRgNC10LLQvtC20L3QvtC1"`

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом грамотно произвести декодирование, чтобы выцепить из текста сообщения нужные мне данные.
Данный сайт-декодер выводит, что описанный выше фрагмент является словом `"Тревожное"`, нужно всего лишь `base64 -> UTF-8`.
https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/

Но мои попытки не увенчались успехом.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: грамотный метод может использовать email API, чтобы MIME сообщения раскодировать. [Пример кода, который печатает письма в заданном диапазоне дат](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22159037/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну тут все очень просто. Берете строку в base64 докодируете ее в байты, а затем в "UTF-8".

```
import base64

print(base64.b64decode("0KLRgNC10LLQvtC20L3QvtC1").decode("UTF-8"))
```

[Живой пример](https://repl.it/repls/MarriedIndolentGalago)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Декодирует сообщение действительно в русский текст! Важное дополнение - если в кодированной строке будет присутствовать лишний, не относящийся к base64 символ, то на выходе будет ошибка. Поэтому совет всем, кто столкнется с подобной проблемой - проверяйте на сайтах-декодерах то, что вы пытаетесь декодировать! Возможно в вашей строке недекодируемый символ.